# Flutter, video_player I/ACodec codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

The videos are mp4. All other videos work fine, but weirdly, only certain videos come out this way.

```
I/ACodec  (27533): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
```

I was offered to change the audio codec while searching.

I tried encoding it with AAC, AC3, and MPEG but couldn't solve it. (I tried with each file)

It's really weird. The audio is a bit stuttering. It doesn't sound very annoying, but it certainly seems to be a bit cut off.

Does anyone know how to do this? Any advice would be appreciated. thank you.

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 8291): Init 6c53ea1 [ExoPlayerLib/2.12.1] [generic_x86_64, Android SDK built for x86_64, unknown, 24]
D/MetadataUtil( 8291): Skipped unknown metadata entry: ������
I/art     ( 8291): Do partial code cache collection, code=25KB, data=24KB
I/art     ( 8291): After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=23KB
I/art     ( 8291): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/VideoCapabilities( 8291): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
I/OMXClient( 8291): MuxOMX ctor
I/MediaCodec( 8291): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 8489985
E/ACodec  ( 8291): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
I/ACodec  ( 8291): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec  ( 8291): codec does not support config operating rate (err -2147483648)
I/OMXClient( 8291): MuxOMX ctor
I/ACodec  ( 8291): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
D/AudioTrack( 8291): Client defaulted notificationFrames to 3675 for frameCount 11025
D/MediaCodec( 8291): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting dataspace on output surface to #104
D/        ( 8291): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x77a6caeb31c0, tid 8420
D/SoftwareRenderer( 8291): setting dataspace on output surface to #104
I/art     ( 8291): Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=59KB
I/art     ( 8291): After code cache collection, code=58KB, data=57KB
I/art     ( 8291): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
```

Comment: Hi, any update ?

Comment: @Matan Marciano hi I still do not understand this error